# Why does a fixture with a CF bulb work on one house circuit but not another working outlet (which is a CFI)?

Tags: electrical

I plug the fixture with the CF bulb into one outlet and it lights.  In the CFI outlet, which works with other fixtures, it doesn't light.

Comment: Is the outlet this fixture does not work in a *GFCI* or an *AFCI* (or both at once), and does it trip when the fixture in question is plugged into it?

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't light"?  Does it trip the GFCI? Do other things work in this socket?

Comment: Is the circuit that the lamp not work on controlled by any of the following types of electronic switch ;occupancy sensor, motion sensor or dimmer switch?